# WebView JavaScript links work on touch but not when using trackball

Tags: android, webview, trackball

I have a simple WebView-based activity that follows the [Hello, WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) example to enable JavaScript and overload `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

This Activity works great when the user touches links on the webpage.  However, if the user uses the trackball and clicks on a link, then the resulting page load shows a page with JavaScript disabled.

```
public class ViewUrl extends Activity {
    protected WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_url);

        final String url = "http://www.opentable.com/phone/reviews.aspx?rid=2947";

        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.widget1);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl( url );
        view.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

The view_url.xml file is straightforward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/widget1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below are some screenshots showing both the correct and incorrect behavior.

Click using Touch (CORRECT):

[Click using Touch (CORRECT) http://img.skitch.com/20090908-g2acnrpb1riuq11ys3p1u6fd4d.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090908-g2acnrpb1riuq11ys3p1u6fd4d.png)

Click using Trackball (INCORRECT):

[Click using Trackball (INCORRECT) http://img.skitch.com/20090908-my23yxakudwhheq875j2hcwg6h.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090908-my23yxakudwhheq875j2hcwg6h.png)

Any ideas how I can fix the Trackball behavior to be the same as the touch behavior?  Or at least enable JS when links are clicked via the trackball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the "Hello, WebView" example is broken.  On the suggestion of someone on the IRC channel, I removed the override of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` and everything seems to work swimmingly.

Revised working code:

```
public class ViewUrl extends Activity {
    protected WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_url);

        final String url = "http://www.opentable.com/phone/reviews.aspx?rid=2947";

        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.widget1);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl( url );
        view.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() ); // probably not necessary if you don't do anything else with the WebViewClient
    }
}
```